# Defining area not to show labels in using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

In a QGIS 3 layout is it possible to define an area (that's being used as an inset)  where labels should not be shown?

So I have

[image]

I'd assume that Position -- Above Map labels would work but the labels still show. The stacking layer is activated if we choose Above Map Layer but then the overview box disappears if I choose the labelled layer.

I know I can make it a solid block but I want the data to show underneath but not the labels.

Comment: I've heard that 'label blocking' should handle this, but not sure if it's working...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a pretty new feature (since 3.8 I believe) in the layout item dialog, where you can use all Mapitems to block labels. Select the map with labels and then click under item properties on the new "label" icon.

[image]

on the next dialog you can choose the items which should be used to block. very cool and new feature of QGIS

[image]